# jquery looping '$.each()' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The jQuery code given below is not working for me. The problem seems to be with `$.each()` because when i try `alert(orders);` or `$mapinfo.append(orders);` instead of the loop, it prints all the data and works fine but inside the loop is gives the error saying:

`SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected` 
inside 
`jquery-1.12.0.min.js (2,4211)`. But i want it to get all the information separately for the next step in my project.

```
success: function(orders){
        $.each(orders, function(i, order){
        $mapinfo.append('<li>'+ order.type +'</li>');
        });  
    }
```

here is the data that is inside `orders`

```
[{"id":"1","lat":"26.260012","lon":"50.615517","type":"Restaurant "},{"id":"2","lat":"26.261667","lon":"50.613792","type":"supermarket"},{"id":"3","lat":"26.260464","lon":"50.612705","type":"Restaurant "},{"id":"4","lat":"26.259348","lon":"50.613049","type":"supermarket"}]?>
```

i have tried writing `jQuery.each()` and `$(orders).each()` but i always get the same error.

Edit1:
after putting a breakpoint at `$.each` here is what's inside the `orders`..

`orders "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"lat\":\"26.260012\",\"lon\":\"50.615517\",\"type\":\"Restaurant \"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"lat\":\"26.261667\",\"lon\":\"50.613792\",\"type\":\"supermarket\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"lat\":\"26.260464\",\"lon\":\"50.612705\",\"type\":\"Restaurant \"},{\"id\":\"4\",\"lat\":\"26.259348\",\"lon\":\"50.613049\",\"type\":\"supermarket\"}]?>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit tells us that `orders` is still a string by the time you receive it. jQuery will parse JSON before calling your callback if you serve the JSON with the correct `Content-Type` (`application/json`), which is best, or if you tell jQuery to expect JSON back by using `dataType: "json"` in your ajax request.

In your case, it looks like that's not happening because there's an error in the JSON right at the end, after the closing `]` on the array:

> ?>

The JSON is otherwise valid, just looks like an error in the PHP file generating the JSON. Correct that and jQuery will probably parse the string before giving it to you; if not, add the `Content-Type` (or add `dataType: "json"`).